# Problema con while al mostrar por pantalla

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla de productos y otra de categorías y quiero mostrar el nombre de la categoría en cada producto.

Las sentencias `sql` están bien ya que me devuelve los resultados que quiero. El problema es que en mi tabla, las categorías se muestran todas en una misma fila.

Adjunto foto y código.

```
<table class="tabla_cat">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Nombre Categoria</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($prod = $productos->fetch_object()) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $prod->id; ?></td>
            <td><?= $prod->nombre; ?></td>
            <td><?= $prod->descripcion; ?></td>
            <td><?= $prod->precio; ?></td>
            <td><?= $prod->stock; ?></td>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php while ($cat = $categorias->fetch_object()) : ?>
            <td><?= $cat->nombre; ?></td>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Asi es como me queda la tabla]

Comment: Porque hay un while dentro del while?

Comment: En un while saco el objeto producto y en el otro while saco el objeto categoria. Esta mal ?  No se muy bien como deberia hacerlo

Comment: La categoria no deberia venir en el mismo query que el producto? si no como sabes de que categoria es?

Comment: La imagen final es como esperas que salga tu tabla o es como te está saliendo en este momento?

Comment: La imagen es como me esta saliendo ahora, deberia salir cada nombre categoria en una fila diferente. En la query del producto viene la categoria_id y en una query aparte hago la relacion con la tabla de categorias.

Comment: Lo he solucionado, haciendo una sola query que recoga todos los datos directamente... Gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la construcción de la tabla HTML.
Con el *tag* `tr` creas una fila, con `td` una celda (o columna) dentro de esa fila. Entonces, lo que tienes en una fila y dentro creas tantos `<td>contenido</td>` como tienes en tu array de resultados.

> Código erróneo:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $prod->id; ?></td>
    <td><?= $prod->nombre; ?></td>
    <td><?= $prod->descripcion; ?></td>
    <td><?= $prod->precio; ?></td>
    <td><?= $prod->stock; ?></td>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php while ($cat = $categorias->fetch_object()) : ?>
    <td><?= $cat->nombre; ?></td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tr>
```

> Código correcto:

```
<?php while ($cat = $categorias->fetch_object()) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $prod->id; ?></td>
        <td><?= $prod->nombre; ?></td>
        <td><?= $prod->descripcion; ?></td>
        <td><?= $prod->precio; ?></td>
        <td><?= $prod->stock; ?></td>
        <td><?= $cat->nombre; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

> Una tabla de ejemplo con 2 filas y 3 columnas:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Prize</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*El ejemplo viene del código que tienes [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_test)*